# How can I Configure two servers (IIS and WAMP) in same system

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7, wamp

In my system I have configured IIS 7.0 for hosting asp.net website. Now I want work also in PHP. So for that I have installed WAMP server in my same machine. But when Iam trying to access the PHP code it is reading only IIS. Do anyone has solution for this? Or can we host/deploy PHP code in IIS?

Comment: PHP is supported under IIS's FastCGI extension.

Comment: The problem is that IIS and Apache want to Listen on the same TCP port (80). Either change the port that IIS or Apache uses. Or if its just a dev machine, Stop or disable IIS while you are doing Apache/PHP development.

Comment: Yeah, right now I have disabled IIS while working on Apache.. But I need permanent solution. I have added PHP handler also can you pls help me Riggs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use IIS and WAMP at same time
instead use PHP Manager for IIS
It can be easily downloaded and installed by 'web platform Installer'
[Download Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)
here

Comment: I have downladed PHP Manager also from WebPlatformInataller. I followed same process mentioned over here: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php

Comment: After installing Web PI, we need to install wincache for handler mapping.. I did now its working fine..Refer URL: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php